# Aptana scaling in windows 8.1 incorrect

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, aptana

I'm trying out Aptana in Windows 8.1 for the first time, but I got some scaling issues:

[image: http://imgur.com/JyxxPJ3]

The buttons/icons are really small.

I'm using an UX305 (Asus) (1920x1080 and 13"inch screen).

Does someone know how to fix this or how to use scaling for this app.

Google didnt help me with this.

Comment: Are you talking about the icons, or the text? Or is it the project you're working on? I doubt there is anything you can do to fix the size of the buttons/icons, but one thing you can try is right-clicking the application's icon, clicking Properties, going to the Compatibility tab, and checking "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings." It won't make it perfect, but it might be better than what you have now. It's worked for me before on other applications. Otherwise, add a Windows 8/Windows 8.1 tag to your question to help it get noticed.

Comment: Yep the icons on the top, Aptana does not have that option :/